# How to install SPC and WorldEdit in an old Minecraft version with the new launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been using the new minecraft launcher to play and old version, beta 1.3. I would like to use single player commands but one of the mod files needs to go into the bin folder. The new launcher doesn't create a bin though, so what should I do? (Someone has probably already asked, but I have no idea how they would word it so I asked on my own :)

Comment: have you checked to see if the bin folder is inside the minecraft.jar file (remember it can be opened up in something like 7-Zip), otherwise your bin folder should be in your appdata/.minecfraft folder like always, if it's not there and a mod needs it then create it yourself

Comment: @BillyMailman I'd say no. That only covers installing mods for the current version of the game in the new launcher. Installing mods for older versions in the new launcher could be very different, depending on whether those versions are exactly the same as they used to be, or whether Mojang has altered them to use the new Game Directory model. I haven't investigated this detail yet, but it's something not covered by the other question.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128502/how-do-i-install-worldedit-for-minecraft-1-6-2

Comment: @Seven this question and the one I noted as a duplicate are both specifically about modding under the new launcher. Even more, they're both about the way the new launcher locates the Minecraft binary files.

Comment: @Billy Which is not actually the problem in this question, as the asker is having no trouble locating the binary.

Comment: @Seven I'll admit, I forgot to cover the case of older mods manually looking for the bin folder, but this is still very much a question of how mods are installed on the new launcher.

Comment: @BillyMailman It's a question about how SPC and WE are installed. Which is fair, because I just installed them and I'm completely unable to get WE to load, no matter what configuration of Game Directory and WorldEdit.jar locations I try. This is interesting...

Comment: So, Vex, here's my initial findings: the version of Beta 1.3_01 available *through the launcher* appears to be unable to load WorldEdit at all in my tests, no matter whether I put the WE jar in .minecraft/bin, .minecraft/[gamedirectory]/bin, or versions/1.3_01/. I'm attempting to find an original copy of Beta 1.3_01 so I can see if they match or are different, to eliminate that possible variable.

Answer (score 2):

My testing shows that although the version of 1.3_01 available through the launcher is compatible with SPC, it is not compatible with WorldEdit. Specifically, it appears to be unable to supply SPC with the necessary information to locate WorldEdit, no matter where it is put.

### Initial testing

I tested this by creating a new profile and asking for version "old beta" 1.3_01. I changed the Game Directory option to add `/betas/1.3_01` to keep it separate from the latest version's files. I ran it to check it was working, then went to `.minecraft/versions/` and copied the `b1.3_01` version folder to `b1.3_01-SPC`, made the edits to names and the JSON file to make it a valid version that the launcher could use, and then launched again to check it was working.

Then I installed SPC (version `(1.3_01-BETA)SinglePlayerCommandsV2.5_1`) by dropping the `.class` files into the `b1.3_01-SPC.jar`, and launched to check that SPC worked. It did.

Then I tried four different configurations of installing `WorldEdit.jar`, then launched the game and attempted to use the `//chunk` command. All four of these configurations failed the test:

1. Game Directory set to add `/betas/1.3` and put WE.jar in `.minecraft/betas/1.3/bin/`.

   This is where SPC should look for WE if it believes the Game Directory is the same as `.minecraft` used to be.
2. Game Directory set to add `/betas/1.3` and put WE.jar in `.minecraft/bin/`.

   This is where SPC should look for WE if it ignores Game Directory and looks in `%AppData%/.minecraft/bin/`.
3. Game Directory set to add `/betas/1.3` and put WE.jar in `.minecraft/versions/b1.3_01-SPC/`.

   This was tested on the thinking that the install instructions noted that "put it in bin/" meant to put it in the same folder as `minecraft.jar`. I thought it unlikely, but worth testing.
4. Game Directory left to its default (`[...]/.minecraft`) and put WE.jar in `.minecraft/bin/`.

   This is where SPC should look for WE if it ignores Game Directory and is hardcoded to look at `.minecraft/bin/` for `WorldEdit.jar`. I was shocked when this failed.

The results of these tests lead me to believe that SPC for 1.3 uses some code to *ask* Minecraft where the bin folder is, and further, I suspected that the version of beta 1.3 available through the launcher has been altered to understand the new `.minecraft` folder layout changes, in particular the ability to specify the Game Directory and the change in the location of the .jar file and platform libraries. If beta 1.3 downloaded by the new launcher is not the same as beta 1.3 that was originally released, then it's entirely possible that the way SPC queries for the location of bin is no longer working in the launcher-provided version.

### Confirming my fears

To test this supposition, I went looking in my jar backups for a beta copy of Minecraft to compare. I don't have a backup of 1.3_01, but I do have a backup of 1.8. I asked the new launcher to install beta 1.8, then did a binary comparison on the two files and yes, they're different. Mojang has updated the betas (and probably alphas) in order for them to use the new folder layout and launcher options, which has apparently broken whatever mechanism SPC used to load WorldEdit in the *original* older versions.

### Two possible solutions, one hard, one unlikely

Therefore, in order to use WorldEdit with an old beta, either you will have to go and find a backup of 1.3_01 and use that, or the SPC author will have to go back and rewrite the old versions of SPC and WorldEdit for compatibility with the "new" old Minecraft versions – which is highly unlikely to happen, of course.

To get an original b1.3_01 `minecraft.jar` legitimately, you will either need to have made a backup of it before, or use [MCNostalgia](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/800346-tool-mcnostalgia-212-with-gui-now-works-with-146/). Unforunately, MCNostalgia hasn't been updated since Minecraft 1.4.7, and because of the way it uses an existing legitimate `minecraft.jar` as a base to apply binary diff patches to recreate an older version, you will *still* need a backup of an original `minecraft.jar` version 1.4.7 or earlier in order for MCNostalgia to work and generate a valid b1.3_01 `minecraft.jar`. Hopefully you have a backup of *some* version earlier than 1.5 that you can start from.

Comment: Alright, I already have a beta 1.3_01 jar I can use. I was just hoping it would be easier to just use the new launcher to flip around the versions. Thanks though!

Comment: @Vex Oh good! Yeah, I like the new launcher a lot, and it's a shame old mods don't all work with the jars it provides, and old original jars won't use the Game Directory setting which is *so* useful to keep modded saves separate.

Answer (score 1):

For the majority of mods anything you used to do in the bin folder should now be done in in the versions>x.x.x folder.

Singleplayer commands however still specifically looks in the bin folder for the worldedit.jar. You should simply create a new folder in the .minecraft directory, name it "bin", and place the file in there. It doesn't matter that there's nothing else.